# CPU Memory Hierarchy: Calculating Average Memory Access Time

Tags: cache

(From Schuam's Outlines Computer Architecture, 2002, page 193, problem 8.7(b))

Suppose I have the following memory hierarchy of:

CPU <-> SRAM <=> DRAM <=> DISK

SRAM  has 5 ns access time

DRAM  has 60 ns access time

DISK  has 7 ms access time.

If the hit rate at each level of memory hierarchy is 80% (Except the last level of DISK which is 100% hit rate), what is the average memory access time from the CPU?

So I start the problem... here are my calculations:

For the DRAM Level the access time is:

$$
T_{DRAM} = (0.8)(60 ns) + (0.2)(7 ms)
$$

$$
T_{DRAM} = 1.448 \mu seconds
$$

For the SRAM/CPU Level the access time is:

$$
T_{SRAM} = (0.8)(5 ns) + (0.2)(1.448 \mu s)
$$

$$
T_{SRAM} = 293.6 ns
$$

Now for the problem,  the solution manual for the book says the answer is:

$$
T_{SRAM} = (0.80)(5 ns) + (0.20)(0.80)(60 ns) + (0.20)(7 ms)
$$

which I calculate to be: 1.4136E-6 seconds and they calculate to be:

$$
T_{SRAM} = 280,0136.6 ns
$$

My answer is "293.6 ns", and the book's solution to the problem is "280,0136.6 ns"

Who is right and why?

Comment: How many ns are in a ms? ;)

Comment: $$1 ms = 10^{-3} sec$$  $$1 \mu s = 10^{-6} sec$$ $$1 ns=10^{-9} sec$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulas look fine to me, but there's an error in the numbers:
$$
T_{DRAM} = (0.8)(60 ns) + (0.2)(7 ms) \\
T_{DRAM} = 1.448 \mu s
$$
This is incorrect, with \$0.2 * 7\$ ms in the sum, the answer should be at least 1.4 **ms**, not **µs**.

Note that 1 ms = 1000 µs = 1 000 000 ns.

Compare:

$$
T_{DRAM} = (0.8)(60 ns) + (0.2)(7000 ns) \\
T_{SRAM} = (0.8)(5 ns) + (0.2)(T_{DRAM}) \\
T_{SRAM} = 293.6 ns
$$

with:

$$
T_{DRAM} = (0.8)(60 ns) + (0.2)(7000000 ns) \\
T_{SRAM} = (0.8)(5 ns) + (0.2)(T_{DRAM}) \\
T_{SRAM} = 280013.6 ns
$$

If you substitute \$T_{DRAM}\$ in the \$T_{SRAM}\$ expression, you get:

$$
T_{SRAM} = (0.8)(5 ns) + (0.2)(0.8)(60 ns) + (0.2)(0.2)(7000000 ns)
$$

The expression you quoted from the book is slightly different (only one \$(0.2)\$ in the last term of the sum). That looks like either an error in the book, or in your quote.

Comment: ahh...ok... i see the error... was using 10^-6 instead of 10^-3...  thanks for confirm that books equation is wrong... but strangely their answer was right in the end...

Comment: Workings/formulas get copied and pasted.  You go back and edit contents.  Sometimes you fix all, sometimes you do not.  Usually you get the final answer correct.

Comment: @MrCasuality Check my update; if the book actually has \$(0.2)(0.2)\$ in the last term of the sum, the equation in the book is _also_ correct!

Comment: typographical error in book... that's what was confusing me.